# Pass JSON String using Ajax in Java EE

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, mongodb

MongoDB doesn't have a built-in RESTFul Interface so I am trying to convert MongoDB Query Result into a String Format and send it over using Ajax but it is giving me an error

**ServletDemo.java : com.mongodb.servlets**

```
public void doPost(...){
    returnString();
}
public String returnString(){
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"));
    DB database = mongoClient.getDB("db");
    DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("coll");
    DBObject getDocs = new BasicDBObject();
    DBCursor cursor = collection.find(getDocs);
    while(cursor.hasNext()){
        returnString += String.format("%s",cursor.next());
    }
    return returnString;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <button>Click Me</button>
    <p></p>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").on("click",function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:'ServletDemo',
                    type:'post',
                    success:function(data) {
                        alert("Success");
                        $('p').html(data);
                    },
                    error:function(msg){
                        alert("Error");
                        console.log(msg);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Error is Alerted with Error Status 405 in Console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changes in ServletDemo.java

Pass the data using response.getWriter() to Ajax Call

```
public void doPost(...){
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"));
    DB database = mongoClient.getDB("db");
    DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("coll");
    DBObject getDocs = new BasicDBObject();
    DBCursor cursor = collection.find(getDocs);
    while(cursor.hasNext()){
        returnString += String.format("%s",cursor.next());
    }
    response.getWriter().write(returnString);
}
```

Working Successfully now...